# Angular forms addControl does not work when using an object as formState

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, reactive

I am not sure if this is a bug, as I have read the documentation and have used forms for while now, and I can't really get this to work.

This line of code **will** work:

```js
this.contactForm.addControl('email', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
```

But when using an **object** as the formState, it **won't** work. Neither of these lines work:

```js
this.contactForm.addControl('email', new FormControl({ value: '' }, Validators.required));

this.contactForm.addControl('email', new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: false }, Validators.required));
```

Using `this.formBuilder.control(...)` results in the same behaviour.

It is important to mention that when using **only** the **value** property in the formState object (first non-working line), the control will be added but with the object `{ value: '' }` as value, and `[Object object]` will be shown in the html input. When also using the **disabled** property (second non-working line), the control won't even be added.

It's like Angular does not recognise that the formState is an object. Am I missing something?

Comment: From Angular docs we can see that while setting the formState object both value and disabled properties are required. What happens when you use ```{ value: '', disabled: false }```?

Comment: It happens the same as if I use `disabled:false`. I will change the example value to `false` to avoid missunderstandings.

Comment: @LukaszGawrys sorry, I meant to say it happens the same as with `true`

Comment: Maybe could you provide a reproducible example because it works for me both with disabled true and false in my local projects?

Comment: I've setup a Stackblitz, and it works there: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-elf3az?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Mm I don't know why, but now it works with `disabled: false`. It doesn't work with `disabled: true`. I also tried to make a reproducible example and it works perfectly well, so it must be because of some implementation error of my own. I'll look into it.